# Grouping with pivot to get count by week

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I Have a table temp_customer. Schema and some data like below-

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[temp_customer](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [company_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [created_by] [int] NULL,
    [created_at] [datetime] NULL,
    [code] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
)
    
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[temp_customer] ON 
     INSERT [dbo].[temp_customer] ([id], [company_id], [created_by], [created_at], [code], [name]) VALUES (1714, 1, 1, CAST(N'2018-02-14 11:43:00.757' AS DateTime), N'STET-00001', N'Stephan Taylor')
    INSERT [dbo].[temp_customer] ([id], [company_id], [created_by], [created_at], [code], [name]) VALUES (1715, 1, 1, CAST(N'2018-02-14 11:43:01.007' AS DateTime), N'TAMJ-00001', N'Tamala Jones')
    INSERT [dbo].[temp_customer] ([id], [company_id], [created_by], [created_at], [code], [name]) VALUES (1716, 1, 2, CAST(N'2018-02-14 11:43:01.457' AS DateTime), N'TARB-00001', N'Taran Blauman')
    INSERT [dbo].[temp_customer] ([id], [company_id], [created_by], [created_at], [code], [name]) VALUES (1718, 1, 1, CAST(N'2019-01-29 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime),  N'VERD-00001', N'Veronica Dave')
    INSERT [dbo].[temp_customer] ([id], [company_id], [created_by], [created_at], [code], [name]) VALUES (1719, 1, 1, CAST(N'2018-02-14 11:43:02.190' AS DateTime), N'WAYD-00001', N'Wayne Dotson')
    INSERT [dbo].[temp_customer] ([id], [company_id], [created_by], [created_at], [code], [name]) VALUES (1720, 1, 2, CAST(N'2018-03-12 07:40:34.107' AS DateTime),  N'LARJ-00001', N'Larry Jacobs')
    INSERT [dbo].[temp_customer] ([id], [company_id], [created_by], [created_at], [code], [name]) VALUES (1721, 1, 2, CAST(N'2018-03-28 03:40:52.673' AS DateTime), N'ROBM-00002', N'Robert Matte') 
    INSERT [dbo].[temp_customer] ([id], [company_id], [created_by], [created_at], [code], [name]) VALUES (1722, 1, 1, CAST(N'2018-03-28 05:09:53.093' AS DateTime),  N'MART-00001', N'Mark Taylor') 
    INSERT [dbo].[temp_customer] ([id], [company_id], [created_by], [created_at], [code], [name]) VALUES (1723, 1, 1, CAST(N'2018-03-28 05:39:19.237' AS DateTime), N'TAYT-00001', N'ALEX  BRUZZI') 
    INSERT [dbo].[temp_customer] ([id], [company_id], [created_by], [created_at], [code], [name]) VALUES (1724, 1, 3, CAST(N'2018-04-04 04:37:29.547' AS DateTime), N'STOCK', N'STOCK')
    INSERT [dbo].[temp_customer] ([id], [company_id], [created_by], [created_at], [code], [name]) VALUES (1725, 1, 3, CAST(N'2018-04-04 06:51:10.797' AS DateTime), N'AMAT-00001', N'Amanda Trezza')
    INSERT [dbo].[temp_customer] ([id], [company_id], [created_by], [created_at], [code], [name]) VALUES (1726, 1, 1, CAST(N'2018-04-04 06:55:04.720' AS DateTime), N'ADRG-00001', N'Adriana Grande')
    INSERT [dbo].[temp_customer] ([id], [company_id], [created_by], [created_at], [code], [name]) VALUES (1727, 1, 3, CAST(N'2018-04-05 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'ISSJ-00002', N'Issac Johnes')
    INSERT [dbo].[temp_customer] ([id], [company_id], [created_by], [created_at], [code], [name]) VALUES (1728, 1, 2, CAST(N'2019-01-18 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime),  N'JACJ-00001', N'Jacob Jensen')
```

it looks like -

[image]

I would like to get output group on created_by with total_customer_created and week in which customer created as individual columns. eg in excel like -
[image]

i.e on basis of Week(starting from monday) , total customer created by 1,2,3..... etc in required date range.

Any helps appreciated in advance.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you *really* using? SQL Server 2005 has been **completely** unsupported for about 6 years, SQL Server 2008 has been *completely* out of support for ~3 years, and 2012 has about 6 weeks of (extended) support left. For any of these versions you should either have upgraded long ago, or be close to finalising your upgrade path. All 3 versions, however, lack significant functionality we take for granted in a supported version.

Comment: @Larnu, i m using 2014.

Comment: On the subject of your question, however, pivoting like this is ***far*** better done in your reporting layer. You would likely have to use dynamic SQL to achieve your actual goal here; do the presentation formatting in the presentation layer and leave the SQL layer to worry about getting the needed data.

Comment: *" i m using 2014"* then why did tag [[tag:sql-server-2005]], [[tag:sql-server-2008]], *and* [[tag:sql-server-2012]]??? *None* of those are [[tag:sql-server-2014]]...

Comment: on tagging option it was not appearing [sql-sevrer-2014]. or may be it was my mistake.

Comment: SQL Server 2014 and 2016 are out of mainstream support. The oldest version still in mainstream support is SQL Server 2017

Comment: How will you display that data? Formatting data like this is really the job of the client, not the database. A PIVOT clause can't have an arbitrary number of columns. That's not a problem for any client language though, which could generate grid columns dynamically

Answer (score 0):

I have found one solution, it is working.

firstly a function to find weeks(with date range)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fGetWeeksList]
(
    @StartDate DATETIME 
   ,@EndDate DATETIME 
)
RETURNS 
TABLE 
AS
RETURN
(
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-(DATEPART(DW,DATEADD(WEEK, x.number, @StartDate))-2),DATEADD(WEEK, x.number, @StartDate)) as [StartDate]
      ,DATEADD(DAY,-(DATEPART(DW,DATEADD(WEEK, x.number + 1, @StartDate))-1) ,DATEADD(WEEK, x.number + 1, @StartDate)) AS [EndDate]
FROM master.dbo.spt_values x
WHERE x.type = 'P' AND x.number <= DATEDIFF(WEEK, @StartDate, DATEADD(WEEK,0,CAST(@EndDate AS DATE)))
)
```

And then use it in below query

```
select cast(cast(fGetWeeksList.startdate as date) as varchar(max)) + ' To '+cast(cast(fGetWeeksList.enddate as date) as varchar(max))   as week_range,
*
into #week_table from fGetWeeksList('01-01-2022','06-02-2022')

select users.user_cd ,
users.first_name ,
users.last_name,
count(customers.id) cust_count,
#week_table.week_range
into #cust_count
from users
inner join customers on 
users.id = customers.created_by
inner join #week_table on
cast(customers.created_at as date) between #week_table.StartDate and #week_table.EndDate
group by 
users.user_cd ,users.first_name ,users.last_name,
#week_table.week_range

DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @columns = N'';
SELECT @columns += N', ' + QUOTENAME(week_range)
  FROM (SELECT distinct #week_table.week_range FROM #week_table 
  GROUP BY #week_table.week_range) AS x;

  print @columns
SET @sql = N'SELECT user_cd,p.first_name,p.last_name, ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM
(
  SELECT p.week_range, p.user_cd,p.first_name,p.last_name, p.cust_count FROM dbo.#cust_count AS p
) AS j
PIVOT
(
  SUM(cust_count) FOR week_range IN ('+ STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '') + ')
) AS p;';
PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

drop table #week_table

drop table #cust_count
```